# Finding all real solutions of $x-8\sqrt{x}+7=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Finding all real solutions of $x-8\sqrt{x}+7=0$.

Man, I tried subtituting $x=y^2$ but IDK things got complicated. What is the best way to figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: How about isolating the square root on one side and then squaring both sides?

Comment: How did things get complicated?  It gets you a quadratic that can be factored by inspection or fed to the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $y=\sqrt{x}$, therefore $y^2=x$

$y^2-8y+7=0$ therefore $(y-7)(y-1)=0$ hence $y=1,7$.

Therefore $x=1,49$. These are indeed the only solutions.

Comment: $\sqrt{y^2} = |y|$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Right, but we can pick a positive $y$ such that $y^2=x$. I edited my answer thanks for the correction.

Comment: Why say "for some $y \ge 0$"? We know *exactly* which $y$.  We are replacing $y = \sqrt x$ and we never concern ourselfs with $\sqrt{y^2}$ ever.

Comment: @fleablood that's better, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Isolate the square root, then square both sides:
\begin{align*}
     x-8\sqrt x+7&=0\\
     \implies x+7&=8\sqrt x\\
     \implies (x+7)^2 &= 64 x\\
     \implies x^2 -50x + 49&=0\\
     \implies (x-49)(x-1) &=0\\
     \implies x = 49 \text{ or } x&=1,
\end{align*}
which are the two solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If

$x - 8\sqrt x + 7 = 0, \tag 1$

then

$x + 7 = 8\sqrt x; \tag 2$

then

$x^2 + 14 x + 49 = (x + 7)^2 = (8\sqrt x)^2 = 64x; \tag 3$

thus

$x^2 - 50x + 49 = 0, \tag 4$

which factors as

$(x - 1)(x - 49) = 
x^2 - 50x + 49 = 0; \tag 5$

thus

$x = 1 \; \text{or} \; x = 49; \tag 6$

it is now a simple matter to check that $1$, $49$ obey (1).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt{x}=a$
$$a^2-8a+7=0$$
Find the factor
$$(a-7)(a-1)=0$$
Then you have
$$a=7\text{ and }a=1$$
Remember that $a=\sqrt{x}$, then
$$x=1 \text{ or } x=49$$

Answer (score 1):

Why did things get compilicated?

If you replace $x$ with $y^2$ and $\sqrt x$ with $y$ you should get

$y^2 - 8y +7 =0$ and that should not be complicated.

========

Factor or use the quadratic formula so

$(y - 7)(y-1) = 0$ so $y = 7$ or $y=1$.

Or $y = \frac {-(-8) \pm \sqrt {64-4*7*1}}2 = \frac {8\pm {36}}2 = \frac {8\pm 6}2=4\pm 3=1,7$; so $y=7$ or $y =1$.

So $x = y^2$ so $x = 7^2 = 49$ or $x = 1$.  Thus are the two solutions.

Check:

If $x = 49$ then $x - 8\sqrt x +7 = 49 - 8*7 + 7 = 49- 56 + 7 = 0$.

And if $x = 1$ then $x - 8\sqrt x + 7 = 1-8*1 + 7 = 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So?  We are substituting $y =\sqrt x$.  And we never calculate $\sqrt {y^2}$.  So where do we ever say anything about $\sqrt{y^2}$?

Comment: I misread the substitution you were making.  Yes, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle x-8\sqrt{x}+7=0$

or, $\displaystyle (\sqrt{x} -1)(\sqrt{x} -7)=0$

Hence, $x = 1$ and $49$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

It can be written as

$$8x-7x-8\sqrt{x}+7=$$
$$8\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)-7(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)=$$

$$(\sqrt{x}-1)\Bigl(8\sqrt{x}-7(\sqrt{x}+1)\Bigr)=$$

$$(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}-7)=0$$

thus...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you made the right substitution $ x = y^{2} $. Using that substitution, $$ y^2 - 8y + 7 $$

Observe that the above function is factorable:

$$ y^2 - 8y + 7 = (y - 7)(y - 1) = 0$$

The solutions for $y$ are $y = 7$ and $y = 1$. Back-substituting to $x$, we have that

$$ x = 49; x = 1 $$